# can't find class

Tags: php, zend-framework

bootstrap.php

```
define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
require_once('Zend/Controller/Front.php');
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->addModuleDirectory(ROOT_DIR . '/application/modules');
$front->dispatch();
```

application/modules/controllers/IndexController.php

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
 public function indexAction() {
  require_once(ROOT_DIR . '/application/models/DbTable/Users.php');
  $users = new Application_Model_DbTable_Users();
 }
}
```

application/models/DbTable/Users.php

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Users extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'users';
}
```

Error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Db_Table_Abstract' not found in /var/www/projects/forum4php/application/models/DbTable/Users.php on line 4 Call Stack: 0.0026 330996  
1. {main}() /var/www/projects/forum4php/bootstrap.php:0 0.0149 1128036  
2. Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch(???, ???) /var/www/projects/forum4php/bootstrap.php:11 0.0326 2499724  
3. Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(???, ???) /var/www/projects/zendframework/Zend/Controller/Front.php:954 0.0416 2810512  
4. Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch(???) /var/www/projects/zendframework/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:295 0.0418 2814860  
5. IndexController->indexAction() /var/www/projects/zendframework/Zend/Controller/Action.php:513 0.0419 2817108  
6. require_once('/var/www/projects/forum4php/application/models/DbTable/Users.php') /var/www/projects/forum4php/application/modules/default/controllers/IndexController.php:4
```

How to make Zend Framework see Application Model DbTable Users?

Update:

```
require_once(ROOT_DIR . '/application/models/DbTable/Users.php');
require_once('Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php');
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
 public function indexAction() {
  $users = new Application_Model_DbTable_Users();
 }
}
```

Error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Db_Table_Abstract' not found in /var/www/projects/forum4php/application/models/DbTable/Users.php on line 3 Call Stack: 0.0024 331316 
1. {main}() /var/www/projects/forum4php/bootstrap.php:0 0.0160 1128364 
2. Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch(???, ???) /var/www/projects/forum4php/bootstrap.php:11 0.0360 2500024 
3. Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(???, ???) /var/www/projects/zendframework/Zend/Controller/Front.php:954 0.0368 2500108 
4. Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->loadClass(???) /var/www/projects/zendframework/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:262 0.0372 2514700 
5. include_once('/var/www/projects/forum4php/application/modules/default/controllers/IndexController.php') /var/www/projects/zendframework/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:344 0.0373 2516956 
6. require_once('/var/www/projects/forum4php/application/models/DbTable/Users.php') /var/www/projects/forum4php/application/modules/default/controllers/IndexController.php:2
```

It still can't see the model...

Update:

```
require_once('Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php');
class Application_Model_DbTable_Users extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
protected $_name = 'users';
```

}

```
Invalid controller specified (error)
#0 /var/www/projects/zendframework/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 /var/www/projects/forum4php/bootstrap.php(11): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 {main}
```

It still can't see the model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application does see find the class `Application_Model_DbTable_Users` but can't find it's base-class `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`.
You'll have to `require_once 'Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php'` it or use an autoloader.

Comment: thats cause you need to require it _before_ you define the class that extends it... try putting the `require` for the abstract before the one for `Users`

Comment: Tried. Now, invalid controller specified. It's almost over. ppl, come back!

Comment: @delirium Your application is trying to load the ErrorController which doesn't exist. Read http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.standard.errorhandler for more information about the error handling with controllers ;)